# Finding the value of $\displaystyle\int_{x_1+x_2}^{3x_2-x_1}\big\{\frac x4\big\}\left(1+\left[\tan\left(\frac{\{x\}}{1+\{x\}}\right)\right]\right)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, definite-integrals

> If $x_1$ and $x_2$ ($x_1\lt x_2$) are two values of $x$ satisfying the equation $\left|2\left(x^2+\frac1{x^2}\right)+|1-x^2|\right|=4\left(\frac32-2^{x^2-3}-\frac1{2^{x^2+1}}\right)$ then find the value of $\displaystyle\int_{x_1+x_2}^{3x_2-x_1}\big\{\frac x4\big\}\left(1+\left[\tan\left(\frac{\{x\}}{1+\{x\}}\right)\right]\right)dx$ (where $\{*\}$ and $[*]$ denotes fractional part function & greatest integer function respectively.)

RHS of the given equation can be written as $6-2^{x^2-1}-\frac1{2^{x^2-1}}=6-(y+\frac1y),$ where $y=2^{x^2-1}$

Since $y\gt0\implies y+\frac1y\ge2\implies  RHS\ge4$

LHS$=\left|2\left(x-\frac1x\right)^2+4+|1-x^2|\right|\ge4\implies 2\left(x-\frac1x\right)^2+4+|1-x^2|\ge4$ (taking only one case as of now)

Thus, $2\left(x-\frac1x\right)^2+|1-x^2|\ge0$, which is true always. Does the question imply there are only two values of $x$ satisfying the given equation?

In any case, how to proceed next?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- By substitution, roots are $\pm 1$. So $x_2=1, x_1=-1$.
- Integral is
  $$\int_0^4 \big\{\frac x4\big\}\left(1+\left[\tan\left(\frac{\{x\}}{1+\{x\}}\right)\right]\right)dx$$
- Argument of $\tan$ is less than $\pi/4$. So greatest integer function returns zero.

**Hint :** Solve the inequality $$\frac{y}{1+y} \ge \frac{\pi}{4}$$

and check range of $y$.

- In $(0,4)$, $x/4 \in (0,1)$ so $$\big\{\frac x4\big\} = \frac{x}{4}$$

Putting together, the intimidating integral reduces to
$$\int_0^4 \frac{x}{4} \, dx$$

Comment: Thanks +1. Can we solve the equation without hit and try?

Comment: @aarbee There is no known method to *exactly* solve general exponential equations.

Comment: Thanks. Could you locate the error in my method because I was getting $x\in\mathbb R$

Comment: Should be $RHS \le 4$ instead of $\ge $

Comment: got it, thanks. In that case, I think the inequality I got gives $x=\pm1$

Comment: Hi. How can we say that the argument of $\tan$ is less than $\dfrac\pi4$?

Comment: If $y \in [0, 1) $,  $$ \frac{y}{1+y} < \frac{1}{2} < \frac{\pi}{4} $$

Comment: $\dfrac12=\dfrac\pi{2\pi}=\dfrac\pi{6...}$. Now $6\gt4$, so, $\dfrac\pi6\lt\dfrac\pi4$. So, $\dfrac12\lt\dfrac\pi4$.

For, $y\in[0,1]$, $y\lt1$ and $1+y\lt2\implies\dfrac1{1+y}\gt\dfrac12$. Also, $\dfrac y{1+y}\lt\dfrac1{1+y}$. So, we have two inequalities: $$\dfrac y{1+y}\lt\dfrac1{1+y}\\\dfrac12\lt\dfrac1{1+y}$$ From this, how do we find relation between $\dfrac y{1+y}$ and $\dfrac12$? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe we can do like this: For $y\in[0,1)$, $\pi y\lt\pi, $and $\pi+\pi y\gt4\implies\dfrac1{\pi+\pi y}\lt\dfrac14$. Multiplying the two fractional inequalities, we get $\dfrac{\pi y}{\pi+\pi y}\lt\dfrac\pi4\implies\dfrac y{1+y}\lt\dfrac\pi4$

Comment: You're complicating simple things. $y < 1 \Rightarrow y+y < y+1 \Rightarrow 2y < y+1 \Rightarrow y/(y+1) < 1/2$. Similarly $4 < 2\pi \Rightarrow 1/2 < \pi/4$. We're taking the numerator to denominator on other side. Yes, we can do the last way.

Comment: Thanks a lot...